# AWS S3 - Scheduled Cleanup of Files - Different Methods

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cron

I'm writing files to AWS S3 for users and there are some images I want to delete after a period of time. (eg: if file has this in name and is older then 48hrs)

One way to do this would be to have a PHP cron job running from EC2 to cleanup where required.

Are there any other ways to do this work?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, provided that the files you want to expire have a common prefix (not just some string somewhere in their names). You can set a Lifecycle policy for the S3 bucket and specify that all files with a specific prefix should expire in a set length of time. S3 will delete all matching file for you.

The prefix can be the empty string to have all files in the bucket expire. The expiration period has to be number of days, and I don't think it's terribly precise. If you say to expire in two days, they won't expire sooner than that, but may stick around for several hours more than 48.

Comment: Here is the link for quick reference : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/LifecycleConfiguration.html